# cokernel of a map

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I'm trying to compute the cokernel of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ where $(a,b) \rightarrow (a+b, a-b)$. I realise that the image of this map is just $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} - \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}  : a \not\equiv b   \text{ mod } 2\}$

Am I right in thinking that its cokernel will just be $\{(0,0), (1,0), (0,1) \}$, I'm not exactly sure how to write this, but my thinking is that the cokernel will be the quotient of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ by the image. This will mean that the elements of the cokernel are not in the image and the different equivalence classes can't be related by an element in $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with $a + b \equiv 0 \text{ mod }2$

Is this correct and if so, is there some better notation I can use to represent this cokernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image, as you say, is the set $H=\{(a,b):a\equiv b\pmod 2\}=
\{(a,b):a+b\text{ is even}\}$.
The cokernel is $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z)/H$ which consists of
the cosets of $H$ in $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$. There are two of these: $H$
and $(1,0)+H=\{(a,b):a+b\text{ is odd}\}$. So the cokernel is
the group of two elements.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I don't need the (0,1) because it's in the coset of (1,0): (1,0) + (-1,1) = (0,1)